# Conditionally Import a range from worksheets

Tags: import, conditional-statements, spreadsheet, importrange

I am using a Google Spreadsheet to display club subscriptions in a web page and although it is working, I am sure there is a better way!
There are different levels of subscription for 'Summer', 'Late summer' and 'Winter' memberships and I have three separate worksheets which are called depending on the date into a 'display sheet' which is built into a webpage.
The formula I have is:-

```
enter code here =if(today()>Summer!B1,importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B_5H55wPWfw3LBckgmzcHfm52Az7yFZAsUXJEns4CdA","Summer!A4:F24"),if(today()>'Late Summer'!B1 , importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B_5H55wPWfw3LBckgmzcHfm52Az7yFZAsUXJEns4CdA","Late Summer!A4:E24"), if(today()> Winter!B1 ,importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B_5H55wPWfw3LBckgmzcHfm52Az7yFZAsUXJEns4CdA","Winter!A4:E24"),"Error")))
```

I have tried the array formula arrayformula() but cannot make anything else work!
Does anyone have a more efficient idea?

Answer (score 0):

Oh gosh... eventually found a way:

```
=if(and(today()>Summer!B1,today()<'Late Summer'!B1),arrayformula(Summer!A4:E24),if(and(today()>'Late Summer'!B1,today()<Winter!B1) , arrayformula('Late Summer'!A4:E24), if(today()> Winter!B1 ,arrayformula(Winter!A4:E24),"Error")))
```